# Unable to change backcolor property in Winforms app (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, backcolor

I am working on a project where I want to have different select-able themes that change the color of certain UI elements. I am trying to change the BackColor property of different controls (buttons, labels, panels, etc), but I an unable to actually change the BackColor. My buttons are on FlatUI, don't have a background image, and UseVisualBackgroundStyle is false. I don't get any errors when I change the BackColor but I can't see it actually changing anything.

My code for creating the one of the buttons:

```cs
this.scriptHubButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(50)))));
this.scriptHubButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
this.scriptHubButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.scriptHubButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Showcard Gothic", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.scriptHubButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
this.scriptHubButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(761, 416);
this.scriptHubButton.Name = "scriptHubButton";
this.scriptHubButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 36);
this.scriptHubButton.TabIndex = 11;
this.scriptHubButton.Text = "More";
this.scriptHubButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
this.scriptHubButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.scriptHubButton_Click);
```

And here's the idea of how I am attempting to change the backcolor:

```cs
public void changeTheme(Color c)
        {
            scriptHubButton.BackColor = c;
        }
```

Edit: I am trying to change this is the main form of my app while it is already being displayed...

Comment: Can you show your code? Have you put a breakpoint in you code to see if it executes.

Comment: @Flydog57 done :)

Comment: Do a Debug Break All to see where the code is running and also look at the trace stack.  You could be blocked and never getting to the code.

Comment: Add `this.Show();` to the bottom snippet, some odds you now see the changes.  Wrong form object reference.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, now that I'm doing that It will make a new form appear with an animation (like the main form) and the correct color, however it disappears immediately after.

Comment: @jdweng I did that and it runs through all the code, but does not make any visible changes.

Comment: Are you adding the button to a parent like a form or another control (panel)? Is parent visible?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for the help :)